# How to to add additional metadata to individual frames, DDB's, when creating an AVI file with ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, bitmap

I'm creating avi videos from device dependent bitmaps, DDB's.

The pipeline is quite simple, a GigE camera provides frame by frame, and each frame, a DDB, is piped to a ffmpeg process creating a final AVI file, using h264 compression.

These videos are scientific in nature, and we would like to store/embed experimental hardware information, such as the states of a few digital lines, with each frame. 
This information need to be available in the final avi video

Question is, is this possible?

Looking at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmap it does not seem that adding additional data to the DDB themselves is possible, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Whether you want the information to be display in video? If you want, you should render the information to bitmap before piped to ffmpeg. If not, you can embed information with XMP to AVI file.  AVI files can embed [Extensible Metadata Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) (XMP).

Comment: AVI is a RIFF storage format that can have any type of chunks ... so find one that is capable of storing your data and include it into the avi stream ... In case this is above your level You can even encode it as sound ... or increase the resolution of image and store the data into the added pixel area but take in mind you are using lossy compression  ...